# How to count the number of times an element is found in an array

Tags: c++

I have a project where I need to write a program that simulates the rolling of a die 6000 times and counts the number of occurrences of each side of the die. As per the instructions I put all 6000 of the random values in an array called num_array.

However, now I have to count how many times each number occurs in num_array and put the value of each into another array called tally_array. tally_array currently has 7 zeroes (one for zero and the other six for each side of the die) but in the end should count the number of occurrences for each side of the die. How am I supposed to count the values of one array and assign them to a place in another array using a loop? I put the code I have so far and the hints my teacher gave me. If you have any ideas please let me know.

```
const int array_size[6000]={};
        int die;
        int num_array[6000]={};
        int tally_array[0,0,0,0,0,0,0];

        srand(185);
        srand(time(0));
        for (int die=0; die < 6000; die++) {
                num_array[die] =  1+(rand() %6);
        }
```

"First, do not use the switch statement or if statements.
This is where we use tally_array with 7 elements - only indexes 1-6 (not 0) will be used to hold the total of each die face values - index 1 will hold the sum of all rolls of 1's, index 2 will hold the sum of all rolls of 2's, etc..

Here's pseudocode for the tallying process:

Loop through every num_array elements (6000 times) with counter i, assign current value of num_array at index i to variable x, access tally_array index x and increment. End loop"

Comment: `tally_array`, as you define it, is an uninitialized array of zero elements.

Comment: As a hint for your problem of counting, think of the values as indexes into `tally_array`.

Comment: Additionally, you only need a single call to `srand()` -- pick one...

Comment: This appears to be a problem that is stated in C rather than in C++. In C++ one could use `std::vector<int>` to store the results and count the occurrences with `std::count`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(num_array)/sizeof(*num_array); i++) {
    int x = num_array[i];
    tally_array[x]++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked really well. I'm new to c++ though so I was curious what does the part below do?
i < sizeof(num_array)/sizeof(*num_array)

Comment: It calculates the number of elements in the array. sizeof(num_array) returns the size in bytes for the whole array. 6*4 == 24 == number of elements * size of an element (here int => 4). But you want to have only the number of elements not bound to the size of the elements in the array array. Hence you divide it by sizeof(*num_array) *num_array == int => all together: 6*4/4== 6 elements.

Comment: But here again, when your numbers are between 1-6 you have to normalize them to 0-5 meaning `int x = num_array[i];`  should be `int x = num_array[i] - 1;`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
        int tally_array[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0, 0};

        srand(185);
        srand(time(0));
        for (int die=0; die < 6000; die++) {
            int randVal = rand() %6;
            tally_array[randVal + 1] += 1;
        }

        for (int i=1; i< 7; ++i)
            printf("%d\n", tally_array[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 6000

void main()
{
        int currentDieGamble;
        int num_array[ARRAY_SIZE]={};
        int tally_array[6] = {0,0,0,0,0,0};

        int counter=0;

        srand(time(0));

        for (currentDieGamble = 0; currentDieGamble < ARRAY_SIZE; currentDieGamble++) {
                num_array[currentDieGamble] =  1 + (rand() %6);
        }

           for (currentDieGamble = 0; currentDieGamble < ARRAY_SIZE; currentDieGamble++) {
                tally_array[num_array[currentDieGamble] - 1]++;
        }

        for (int dieCounter = 0; dieCounter < 6  ; dieCounter ++)
        {
                printf("\nThe die side %d appeared %d times out of %d gambles. ",
                    dieCounter + 1 ,tally_array[dieCounter],ARRAY_SIZE);
        }
}
```

just change main() to whatever your function name is supposed to be.
enjoy! :)

edited: had little bug with indexes, fixed it.

Comment: I think `tally_array[num_array[currentDieGamble]]++;` should be `tally_array[num_array[currentDieGamble]-1]++;`

Answer (score 0):

I think using std::count is the best way to do this, if you are allowed to use the Standard Library. The following Code might be helpful just to count the occurence after you are done generating everything.

`

```
std::vector<int> dicenumbers={1,2,3,4,5,6}; 
std::vector<int> num_array = {}; 
std::vector<int> tally= {}; 
int countnum=0; 

for(int i : dicenumbers)
{
countnum  = std::count(std::begin(num_array), std::end(num_array), i); 
tally.push_back(countnum); 

}
```

`